# Java Splitting With Math Expression

Tags: java, math

I am trying to split a Math Expression.

```
String number = "100+500";

String[] split = new String[3];
```

I want to make

- split[0] = "100"
- split[1] = "+"
- split[2] = "500"

I tried this but I don't know what to write for splitting.

```
split = number.split(????);
```

Comment: Why do you want to split it? To write a parser or to evaluate the expression? In both cases split is probably not the right tool.

Comment: @assylias I am making a GUI Calculator for Big Integers. After splitting, I will check which operator used, then I will evaluate it.

Comment: Split uses regex, so this may be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463048/ruby-find-a-whole-math-expression-in-a-string-using-regex

Comment: Ah shoot, I misread this question.  Split probably is not the best tool for the job, as it will consume the character it's splitting on.

Comment: @Makoto yeah I tried it but I couldn't get the operator. I will just use +,- and * operators so all I have to do is split these 3.

Comment: This is not as easy as splitting strings - see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792261/java-maths-parsing-api

Comment: If you really want to use split, then use something like tihs [`"100+500".split("(?<=\\+)|(?=\\+)")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to split between digits and non-digits without consuming any input... you need look arounds:

```
String[] split = number.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
```

What the heck is that train wreck of a regex?

It's expressing the initial sentence of this answer:

- `(?<=\d)` means the previous character is a digit
- `(?=\D)` means the next character is a non-digit
- `(?<=\d)(?=\D)` together will match *between* a digit and a non-digit
- `regexA|regexB` means either regexA *or* regexB is matched, which is used as above points, but non-digit then digit for the visa-versa logic

An important point is that look arounds are *non-consuming*, so the split doesn't gobble up any of the input during the split.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String number = "100+500-123/456*789";
String[] split = number.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Output:

```
[100, +, 500, -, 123, /, 456, *, 789]
```

---

To work with numbers that may have a decimal point, use this regex:

```
"(?<=[\\d.])(?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])(?=[\\d.])"
```

which effectively just add `.` to the characters that are a "number".

Comment: It worked... but how? What does "(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)" mean?

Comment: @Dosher: Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/. Predefined Character classes will explain what the \d and \D do. The other methods should explain the rest of the regex.

Comment: @Bohemian That helped me a lot, now I understand it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @realNameDoesn'tExist  see additions to answer

Comment: How would you update this regex to split parenthesis from other types of the string? would you need another barrel condition in there?

Comment: @Narshe add this: `(?=[()])|(?<=[()])`, ie `"(?<=[\\d.])(?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])(?=[\\d.])|(?=[()])|(?<=[()])"` to split before and after brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Off the bat, I don't know any library routine for the split. A custom splitting routine could be like this:

```
/**
 * Splits the given {@link String} at the operators +, -, * and /
 * 
 * @param string
 *            the {@link String} to be split.
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             when the given {@link String} is null.
 * @return a {@link List} containing the split string and the operators.
 */
public List<String> split(String string) throws NullPointerException {
    if (string == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("the given string is null!");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    // operators to split upon
    String[] operators = new String[] { "+", "-", "*", "/" };

    int index = 0;
    while (index < string.length()) {
        // find the index of the nearest operator
        int minimum = string.length();
        for (String operator : operators) {
            int i = string.indexOf(operator, index);
            if (i > -1)
                minimum = Math.min(minimum, i);
        }

        // if an operator is found, split the string
        if (minimum < string.length()) {
            result.add(string.substring(index, minimum));
            result.add("" + string.charAt(minimum));
            index = minimum + 1;
        } else {
            result.add(string.substring(index));
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Some test code:

```
System.out.println(split("100+10*6+3"));
System.out.println(split("100+"));
```

Output:

```
[100, +, 10, *, 6, +, 3]
[100, +]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Pattern/Matcher classes in Java:

```
    String expression = "100+34";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)|(\\+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(expression);
    String[] elems = new String[m.groupCount() +1];
    int i=0;

    while(m.find())
    {
        elems[i++] = m.group();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something simple instead of insane regex; just pad `+` with white space:

```
String number = "100+500";
number = number.replace("+", " + ");
```

Now you can split it at the white space:

```
String[] split = number.split(" ");
```

Now your indices will be set:

```
split[0] = "100";
split[1] = "+";
split[2] = "500";
```

To check for all arithmetic symbols, you can use the following method if you wish to avoid regex:

```
public static String replacing(String s) {
   String[] chars = {"+", "-", "/", "="};

   for (String character : chars) {
      if (s.contains(character)) {
         s = s.replace(character, " " + character + " ");//not exactly elegant, but it works
      }
   }
   return s;
}

//in main method
number = replacing(number);
String[] split = number.split(" ");
```

Comment: That is a great method for me but I also need to split - and *. Will number = number.replace("+", " + " || "-", " - " || "*", " * "); work? --Edit : OK it didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, you would have to include a `.replace()` for every character you wish to pad for this technique to work. A workaround is to create a method that will check for all areas desired to split, and constantly update the String, then return it. Your characters, such as `*` and `-` can be placed in an array to be iterated through. The benefit is you only have to write `replace()` once, so your code will look more elegant. Performance would still be the same though.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your expression string, then in result having pure tokens and categorized tokens. The [mXparser](http://mathparser.org/) library supports this as well as the calculation process. Please follow the below example:

Your very simple example "100+500":

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Expression e = new Expression("100+500");
mXparser.consolePrintTokens( e.getCopyOfInitialTokens() );
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  --------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] | Expression tokens: |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |    TokenIdx |       Token |        KeyW |     TokenId | TokenTypeId |  TokenLevel |  TokenValue |   LooksLike |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           0 |         100 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           0 |       100.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           1 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           2 |         500 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           0 |       500.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

More sophisticated example "2*sin(x)+(3/cos(y)-e^(sin(x)+y))+10":

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Argument x = new Argument("x");
Argument y = new Argument("y");
Expression e = new Expression("2*sin(x)+(3/cos(y)-e^(sin(x)+y))+10", x, y);
mXparser.consolePrintTokens( e.getCopyOfInitialTokens() );
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  --------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] | Expression tokens: |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |    TokenIdx |       Token |        KeyW |     TokenId | TokenTypeId |  TokenLevel |  TokenValue |   LooksLike |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           0 |           2 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           0 |         2.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           1 |           * |           * |           3 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           2 |         sin |         sin |           1 |           4 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           3 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           4 |           x |           x |           0 |         101 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           5 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           6 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           7 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           8 |           3 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           1 |         3.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           9 |           / |           / |           4 |           1 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          10 |         cos |         cos |           2 |           4 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          11 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          12 |           y |           y |           1 |         101 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          13 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          14 |           - |           - |           2 |           1 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          15 |           e |           e |           2 |           9 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          16 |           ^ |           ^ |           5 |           1 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          17 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          18 |         sin |         sin |           1 |           4 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          19 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           4 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          20 |           x |           x |           0 |         101 |           4 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          21 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           4 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          22 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          23 |           y |           y |           1 |         101 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          24 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          25 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          26 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          27 |          10 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           0 |        10.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To understand what Token.tokenId and Token.tokenTypeId means you need to refer to the [API documentation](http://mathparser.org/api/) and parsertokens section. For instance in Operator class you have

1. Operator.TYPE_ID - this corresponds to Token.tokenTypeId if Token is recognized as Operator
2. Operator.OPERATOR_NAME_ID - this corresponds to Token.tokenId if Token is recognized as particular OPERATOR_NAME.

Please follow [mXparser tutorial](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/) for better understanding.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Since +,-,* basically all mathematically symbols are special characters so you put a "\\" before them inside the split function like this

```
String number = "100+500";
String[] numbers = number.split("\\+");
for (String n:numbers) {
  System.out.println(n);
}
```