# how to split string and store in string array with character

Tags: java, string

Given this string:

```
String number = "1234*987-654";
```

I want split and store in string array like `[1234, *, 987, -, 654]`

How I achieve this?

Comment: `number.split("\\b")`

Answer (score 1):

You could try splitting using lookarounds:

```regex
(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)
```

Sample script:

```
String number = "1234*987-654";
String[] parts = number.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
// [1234, *, 987, -, 654]
```

The logic here it split at the interface between any non digit and digit character, or vice-versa.  Note that because we split using purely lookarounds, no characters actually get consumed.

Comment: Looks [familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808112/java-splitting-with-math-expression) ‍♂️

Comment: @Bohemian For the record, I never have ever seen your answer, what I wrote above is my own content alone.

Comment: I don’t doubt your integrity, ever. LOL I didn’t realise I answered the dupe when I duped this Q out. But I knew there were dupes out there and just found this first one that matches. Nevertheless, this is a well worn question.

Comment: Agreed on the dupe...of _something_.  Then again, it's Sunday on SO.  You have two choices: answer less than perfect questions, or get no points haha `:-)`

Comment: **Thank you friends. I solved finally with your help. Have a nice day**